# How do List<T> and List<? extends T> differ in these examples?

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning about Java generics and I'm writing a simple method to find the index of the "smallest" item in a given list.

```java
  public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int findSmallestIndex(List<T> itemList) {

    T smallest = itemList.get(0);
    int smallestIndex = 0;

    int comparison;
    for (int i = 1; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
      comparison = smallest.compareTo(itemList.get(i));

      if (comparison > 0) {
        smallest = itemList.get(i);
        smallestIndex = i;
      }
    }

    return smallestIndex;
  }
```

I'm creating two very simple custom classes to test this out:

```java
class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle>{
  double price;

  public Vehicle(double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Vehicle o) {
    return (int) (price - o.price);
  }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  String label;

  public Car(double price, String label) {
    super(price);
    this.label = label;
  }
}
```

And I ran the example this way:

```java
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    vehicles.add(new Vehicle(499));
    vehicles.add(new Vehicle(390));
    vehicles.add(new Car(360, "Mazda6"));
    vehicles.add(new Car(1000, "Camry"));
    System.out.println(findSmallestIndex(vehicles));
```

My method was declared like this:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int findSmallestIndex(List<T> itemList)
```

so I did not expect my example to run because I thought `T` was inferred to be strictly of type `Vehicle`. However it worked fine. Why does the code work? Shouldn't I declare my method like below? What are the differences between the two declarations?

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int findSmallestIndex(List<? extends T> itemList)
```

Comment: T is a vehicle. A car is a vehicle. There doesn't really seem to be a question here. Also, your comparable is Comparable<? super T>. So you could also use a list of Cars, because they're Comparable<Vehicle>. The second example shouldn't work without being explicit about the type. `Main.<Vehicle>findSmallest( listOfCars)`

Comment: You’re accepting a `List<Vehicle>` as that’s what you’ve declared. What you’ve added to it doesn’t matter.

Comment: It's pretty clear that it works if you know that `Vehicle v = new Car(sthsth)` is ok. Every car is a vehicle and can be assigned to a vehicle variable -- that's how classes work in java. edit: with regard to adding cars to the array, Boris the Spider got it right

Comment: @matt I guess what I'm trying to ask is: if I change the the list type to `List<? extends T>`, how is that different from `List<T>`?

Comment: In this case there is no difference as `T` is only bound once. It would mean though, that the compiler wouldn’t allow you to `add` to the received `List` which is probably no bad thing.

Comment: @JSstarter The difference is that a `List<? extends Vehicle>` might be a `List<Car>`. A `List<Vehicle>` must be a `List<Vehicle>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, this does not much make much difference:

- `List<? extends T>`
- `List<T>`

because you're calling a generic method itself, which on each call can adjust T to match exactly your input. So no matter if you're calling

```
final List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(findSmallestIndex(vehicles));
```

or

```
final List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(findSmallestIndex(cars));
```

the type T

- in the first call will be `Vehicle` (so the parameter `itemList` is `List<Vehicle>`),
- and in the second call T will be `Car` (so the parameter `itemList` is `List<Car>`).

### So why does Java have the 'extends'/'super' magic?

The short answer is: manual control of *covariance* and *contravariance* (because pure Java Generics are *invariant*)

And for the long answer, check the following code:

We have our own List:

```
static class MyList<T> {
    public boolean containsAll(final List<T> pItem) {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean containsAll_extends(final List<? extends T> pItem) {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean containsAll_super(final List<? super T> pItem) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And we use it in this way:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final MyList<Vehicle> vehicles = new MyList<>();
    final MyList<Car> cars = new MyList<>();

    final ArrayList<Vehicle> otherVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Car> otherCars = new ArrayList<>();

    { // Try #1
        vehicles.containsAll(otherVehicles);
        vehicles.containsAll(otherCars); // will NOT compile!

        cars.containsAll(otherVehicles); // will NOT compile!
        cars.containsAll(otherCars);
    }


    {// Try #2
        vehicles.containsAll_extends(otherVehicles);
        vehicles.containsAll_extends(otherCars);

        cars.containsAll_extends(otherVehicles); // will NOT compile!
        cars.containsAll_extends(otherCars);
    }

    {// Try #3
        vehicles.containsAll_super(otherVehicles);
        vehicles.containsAll_super(otherCars); // WILL NOT compile!

        cars.containsAll_super(otherVehicles);
        cars.containsAll_super(otherCars);
    }
}
```

**Observations:**

- This time `MyList<Vehicle> vehicles` will be fixed to the type `MyList<Vehicle>`
- and thus the inner T of vehicles will always be `Vehicle`
- this usage in a *generic `Class`/`Object`* is **opposed** to your use of a *generic method*.
- - Remember: each time you called the *generic method*, the type T could be freely adjusted to the input.
- - Here in my example, the type T (of `vehicles`) is **locked** to type `Vehicle` (and the type T of `cars` is locked to type `Car`)

*Try #1:*

- thus the method `vehicles.containsAll()` will accept `List<T>` => `List<Vehicle>`
- it would also accept `ArrayList<T>` => `ArrayList<Vehicle>`, because we can cast `ArrayList<Vehicle>` into `List<Vehicle>`
- it would NOT accept `List<Car>` or `ArrayList<Car>`, because we CANNOT cast `List<Car>` into `List<Vehicle>` because the generic parameter is *invariant*
- - you can still add `Car` (or any other subclass of `Vehicle`) to `List<Vehicle>`, but you **can not cast** `List<Car>` into `List<Vehicle>`
- - I added an example of casting lists at the bottom of this answer

*So, we give it some variance, introducing:*

- `<? super T>` for contravariance
- `<? extends T>` for covariance

So now we can do: check Try #2:

- `vehicles.containsAll_extends()` accepts `List<? extends T>`, so any List where ? is the subclass (or class itself) of T
- T is still bound as `Vehicle`, so it will accept any List of a subclass of Vehicle
- `otherCars` is of type `ArrayList<Car>`, which fits the description, because
- - `ArrayList` is a subclass of `List`
- - and `Car` is a subclass of `Vehicle`
- so `vehicles.containsAll_extends(otherCars);` is valid and will be accepted by the compiler
- because both relations (ArrayList -> List) and (Car -> Vehicle) are "is subclass of", this is called "co-variant", so varying in(to) the same direction

And what can we learn from Try #3?

- This demonstrates contra-variance
- - `ArrayList` is a **sub**class of `List`
- - and `Vehicle` is a **super**class of `Car`
- thus this is called *contra-variance*

**Casting Lists:**

This example shows how we can use *variance* with *Generics* so we can allow more flexibility:

```
    final ArrayList<Vehicle> otherVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Car> otherCars = new ArrayList<>();

    final ArrayList<? extends Vehicle> otherVehicles2 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    otherVehicles = otherVehicles2; // will NOT compile!
    otherVehicles = otherCars; // will NOT compile!
    otherVehicles2 = otherVehicles;
    otherVehicles2 = otherCars;
```

**Best Practices:**

1. You want to keep your **output** as specific as possible:

- use the most specific types:
- - do NOT write `List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();`, because the information that it's an `ARRAYList` will get lost (to the coder; at runtime, Java will still know it's an `ArrayList`, but you and fellow programmers might get some ugly time checking it with `instanceof` if you abandon the explicit type in the code)
- - instead, write `ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();` or `ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();` for Java 1.7+
- - preserving that information often makes a difference later, for example when using index-based sorting, or relying on a Map being sorted (`SortedMap` or `TreeMap` as opposed to the 'chaotic sorting' of `HashMap`)

2. You want to keep your **input** as generic as possible (as long as the code stays clean)

- so for most testing/adding methods, allow all classes you can work on; for generic types that is usually subclasses, for the main type (`ArrayList`) it's very often superclasses (so usually a contravariant approach)
- - instead of writing `boolean containsItems(ArrayList<Vehicle> items) {...}`
- - you want to write `boolean containsItems(List<? extends Vehicle> items) {...}` (contravariant in main type: ArrayList->List, covariant on the generics:  -> <? extends Vehicles>)
- - or even write `boolean containsItems(Collection<? extends Vehicle> items) {...}` (more contravariance on main type: List->Collection)
- - or even better: `boolean containsItems(Iterable<? extends Vehicle> items) {...}` if you only want to iterate over the items (even more contravariance on main type: Collection->Iterable)
- - note: ArrayList extends List implements Collection implements Iterable, so you go up that inheritance tree as far as it's acceptable for your code
- in contrast `boolean containsItems(Object items) {...}`
- - will do you no good, because then you'd have to manually check for all possible types
- - and use a lot of Reflection to ensure type safety of generic parameters, which results in a ton of code
- - in Java, this all is meant to be handled by the compiler, to get compile time errors (red underlines in your code). This is why Java uses *strong/strict types* in the first place, to save us from `RuntimeExceptions` (`ClassCastException`) and to make the code safe to run (no accidental writing/reading into unrelated RAM)

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. I have a lot to learn from this, it is very helpful.

Comment: This is a very beautiful and thorough explanation to some of my confusions. Initially I thought that if `T` is inferred to be of type `Vehicle`, then `List<T>` (or `List<Vehicle>` in this case) must contain all instances of `Vehicle`, which was not correct. I now realize that even if a list is declared as `List<Vehicle>`, it can contain any instances of `Vehicle` or any instances of `Vehicle`'s subclasses. In this case, the content of the list "almost" didn't matter, what matters is what type of the list it is and whether that type conforms to the rules set by the generic method declarations.

Comment: To be even more specific, I explained some thing in more detail, and I added the *Best Practices* paragraph, you get a real-world example of how to use variance for good code.

Comment: Once again amazing explanation and I learned a lot from you answer. Not only did it answer my first question, but also helped me answer some other questions I had. Before, I always wonder why people always use `List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();` instead of just using `ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();`, and I didn't have a good explanation for it. Now I'm starting to get it and I appreciate you for taking your time to help me understand these concepts. Thank you so much!